# What regulations have been made under S2 Housing Act 2004?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, regulations

The Secretary of State is thereunder to make regulations prescribing categories of housing hazards. Where are these to be found?

Comment: Start by searching the UK legislation website: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi?text=%22Housing%20Act%202004%22%20%22hazard%22

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93375/what-is-compensation-under-the-homes-fitness-for-human-habitation-act-2018-con

Answer (score 3):

[Section 2](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/2?timeline=false) Housing Act 2004 states:

> Meaning of “category 1 hazard” and “category 2 hazard”
>
> (1) In this Act—
>
> - “category 1 hazard” means a hazard of a prescribed description which falls within a prescribed band as a result of achieving, under a prescribed method for calculating the seriousness of hazards of that description, a numerical score of or above a prescribed amount;
> - “category 2 hazard” means a hazard of a prescribed description which falls within a prescribed band as a result of achieving, under a prescribed method for calculating the seriousness of hazards of that description, a numerical score below the minimum amount prescribed for a category 1 hazard of that description; and
> - “hazard” means any risk of harm to the health or safety of an actual or potential occupier of a dwelling or HMO which arises from a deficiency in the dwelling or HMO or in any building or land in the vicinity (whether the deficiency arises as a result of the construction of any building, an absence of maintenance or repair, or otherwise).
>
> (2) In subsection (1)—
>
> “prescribed” means prescribed by **regulations made by the appropriate national authority** (see section 261(1)); and
>
> - “prescribed band” means a band so prescribed for a category 1 hazard or a category 2 hazard, as the case may be.
>
> (3) Regulations under this section may, in particular, prescribe a method for calculating the seriousness of hazards which takes into account both the likelihood of the harm occurring and the severity of the harm if it were to occur.
>
> (4) In this section—
>
> - “building” includes part of a building;
> - “harm” includes temporary harm.
>
> (5) In this Act “health” includes mental health.

For [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) these regulations are:

- [The Housing Health and Safety Rating System (England) Regulations 2005](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2005/3208/contents/made)
- [The Housing Health and Safety Rating System (Wales) Regulations 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/wsi/2006/1702/contents/made)